# Unable to add-pssnapin microsoft.exchange.management.powershell.admin to powershell studio script

Tags: powershell, powershell-studio

Running powershell v2 with exchange management console 2007 installed.

a powershell prompt shows the registered snapings:

```
PS P:\> get-pssnapin -registered | fl name
Name : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
Name : Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Support
```

I can run exchange related commands from a powershell prompt, however, powershell studio 2012 doesnt seem to recognize the addin.  In my _load method, I have

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.admin
```

But get this when I run the script:

```
ERROR: Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2.
```

Powershell studio is the trial version and running v2 as well.

Maybe some snappins do not load with the trial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem may come from the fact that PrimalScript 2012 and [PowerShell Studio 2012](http://www.sapien.com/software/powershell_studio) are 32 bit executables.

Have you got the two modes allowed in PowerShell Studio 2012 ?

[image]

Comment: ah hah!  Thank you @JPBlanc!   I switched to 64bit and no errors were thrown.